# How to check if there is already a swap area?

Tags: partitioning, ram, swap, lvm

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop with 4 GB RAM.  I had chosen option to "replace Windows 8 and install Ubuntu with LVM" when installing Ubuntu. Now I wanted to create a swap partition, I executed following commands:

```
sudo fallocate -l 2048m /mnt/swap_file.swap
sudo chmod 600 /mnt/swap_file.swap
sudo mkswap /mnt/swap_file.swap
sudo swapon /mnt/swap_file.swap
```

Then when I opened my editor to edit /etc/fstab it already had an entry for swap as:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

So I did following commands:

```
sudo swapoff /mnt/swap_file.swap
sudo rm /mnt/swap_file.swap
```

Now my question is if there is already an swap area how can I check its size and  how can I increase it if I want. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways for it, here are my favourite ones-

1. Type in the terminal and press Enter:

   ```
    cat /proc/swaps
   ```
2. Type in the terminal and press Enter:

   ```
   swapon -s
   ```
3. Type in the terminal and press Enter:

   ```
   free
   ```